# BUILD with Ant FAILED for Android on a Linux machine but succeeded on a Mac machine

Tags: android, linux, ant, build

I am trying to build android project using ant from a linux machine. The project builds with no issues on my Mac machine but on the linux machine. Cannot seem to figure out why!

I typed

```
ant release
```

Then I received the following message:

```
 BUILD FAILED
/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:885: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:887: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:899: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:281: null returned: 137
```

and the lines in build.xml file are

```
275 <dex executable="${dx}"
276                    output="${intermediate.dex.file}"
277                    dexedlibs="${out.dexed.absolute.dir}"
278                    nolocals="@{nolocals}"
279                    forceJumbo="${dex.force.jumbo}"
280                    disableDexMerger="${dex.disable.merger}"
281                    verbose="${verbose}">
      <path path="${out.dex.input.absolute.dir}"/>
      <path refid="out.dex.jar.input.ref" />
      <external-libs />
    </dex>
.
.
.
.
.

884   <target name="-dex" depends="-compile, -post-compile, -obfuscate">
885      <do-only-if-manifest-hasCode elseText="hasCode = false. Skipping...">
886      <!-- only convert to dalvik bytecode is *not* a library -->
887      <do-only-if-not-library elseText="Library project: do not convert bytecode..." >
888         <!-- special case for instrumented builds: need to use no-locals and need
889                 to pass in the emma jar. -->
890            <if condition="${build.is.instrumented}">
891                <then>
892                    <dex-helper nolocals="true">
893                        <external-libs>
894                            <fileset file="${emma.dir}/emma_device.jar" />
895                        </external-libs>
896                    </dex-helper>
897                </then>
898                <else>
899                    <dex-helper />
                </else>
            </if>
        </do-only-if-not-library>
    </do-only-if-manifest-hasCode>
</target>
```

I hope someone can help

Comment: What is your classpath on the Mac

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution. It seems that it's a permission issue. When building on linux I have to have write, and execute permissions.

Comment: I am having the same symptom.  On what directories or files did you have to grant permissions?

Comment: The /android/android-sdk-linux directory